# Disable First Fragment When User is in Second Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, hide

I make an app and included view pager circle indicator in the starting of the application as a start up tutorial. The first fragment screen shows the name of the application, second  fragment screen shows basic steps for using the application while third screen shows that you are ready to use the app and then the app started. Now the Problem is that i want to disable the first fragment screen when the user is in Second fragment screen so that the SPLASH screen fragment screen doesn't show again on page swip. When the user go to second fragment then the first screen gets disabled/locked/hide anything that doesn't allow the user to move to first screen.

Here is my code for onPageChangeListener

```
private void setTab(){
        _mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener(){

                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {}
                    @Override
                    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {}
                    @Override
                    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        btnAction(position);
                        if (position == 1)
                        {

                        }

                    }

                });
```

Now i tried something in position like this:

```
if (position == 1)
{
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(LayoutOne.newInstance(getApplicationContext())).commit();
}
```

But it doesnot work. Please Help what to do to hide/disable/lock the first fragment screen

Comment: The best solution will be to remove the concerned fragment from the viewpager. Take a look at this library https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-pager

Answer (score 0):

```
       private Fragment fr;
       private FragmentTransaction ft;
       fr = new NextFragment();
       ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
       ft.replace(R.id.your_replace_container, fr).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

You can start/Call your new Fragment by replacing it by the old fragment just like:

```
       ft.replace()...
```

and you can add old one to the stack so that on back key you get the old fragment on screen from where you moved!

```
      ft.replace()...addToBackStack()... //on back key
```

Try edit or do something like above.

Comment: so what do to actually want to achieve?

Comment: if you are using splash screen with threads or timer the double check to stop the thread then move on to next fragment else post some code here

Answer (score 0):

You should use FragmentPagerAdapter for handlig the navigation of fragments and set that adapter in viewpager

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code. It will be helpful for you.

```
FragmentTransactionfragmenttransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
FirstFragment regcomplainfragment = new FirstFragment();
fragmenttransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, regcomplainfragment).addToBackStack("tag");
fragmenttransaction.commit();
```